# Android - Disable/Enable charging

Tags: android, kernel, battery

I would like to know how could I force android to stop charging at a certain level, and then re-enable charging at a lower level.Mainly, I want to avoid the overheating of the battery and always keeping the battery at 100% is not good for li-ion batteries.

Device is Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 10.1

Can it be done in /sys/class/power_supply... in modifying a certain file?
If it can be done in the kernel, what would be the files I should be looking at?

Why I want to do that?Because...

I have few of these tablets ALWAYS plugged and YES the batteries SWOLLEN and I would like to avoid this.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I think it can not be achieved with sysfs level.
How about some applications like task? Latest android has a new quick panel for charging. I saw it can limit to charge if you want to stop, though the TA is connected.
I think you can fix kernel charging driver, however it will definitely be a tough way...